# Found hostages dead. Is it a bug?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

First mission : Milwaukee Junction

In the first play-through, I completed the Typhoon objective first and found the hostages already dead when I arrived at the office where they were held. I figured that the gas bomb was activated when I was discovered by PF members. Also, I did not discover the overhead vent passage until much later.

Today, in my second play-through, I reload the first save file (and skip the lab attack tutorial). I intended to save the hostages but I keep finding them gassed to death. Even using the overhead passage, I saw them dead through the window. I reload the mission 3 times and they ended up dead each time.

At one time, while waiting in the clean room (as a cover for game level loading), I spot a subtitle text "Dispersal device activated. Have a nice day."

Giving up, I deleted the save file. I guess the only option left is to play from the start.

Did it happen to anyone else?

Comment: Hmmm, i failed in stopping the bomb aswell in the beginning, but when i reloaded they were alive again. Maybe its because they are already dead when you load the game? Btw just rushing in and typing the code works too :p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know that if you wait too long at the HQ before boarding the chopper, the hostages can get killed.

When it says you should hurry up and talk to David Sarif, it means it :)

I had a friend that had that happen to him, needless to say David was pretty pissed :)

Comment: This is the reason. While you loiter around at your HQ after David Sarif told you to meet him in the helicopter, he'll give you later two timed messages, the first to hurry up because the situation cannot wait, and the second he'll say something like "Something really bad happened while you were wasting your time! Hurry up we cannot lose more time!" At that second message, I'm 100% sure the hostages were already killed even before you started the mission.

Comment: This happened to me because I was looking around Sarif HQ for energy bars - my flatmate couldn't stop laughing. Now every time I check the fridge for something to eat he accuses me of leaving people to die <:(

Comment: I guess this is a plausible reason. I did loiter around in the first PT as well. That means the save file is 'fated' to send the hostages to their end.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of getting inside the hostage room and disarming the gas dispersal device before it goes off.

I've successfully done this in both playthroughs so far and especially the first time I played through the area I was anything but quick in getting to them. You're *probably* looking at a bug.

- **ETA** Getting noticed by the terrorists does not trigger early release of the gas, as far as I'm aware. I was spotted more than once on my first playthrough (still getting used to the controls and not terribly good yet at checking angles of sight will do that to you) and there were still a couple minutes on the clock when I started hacking the gas bomb.
- **ETA 2** Spoiler warning, but if you want to be absolutely sure it's a bug and not just you, you can try following the walkthrough given [here](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Securing_Sarif%27s_Manufacturing_Plant).

Comment: I played stealth in my second PT. I was vexed out when I found them dead after popping open the vent at the office.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by ETA? I know ETA as 'Estimated Time of Arrival'.

Comment: It can also stand for Edited To Add in this context.

Comment: Never heard ETA as Edited to Add... "Edit" & "Edit2" would be clearer.

Comment: Not sure why someone decided to downvote a four-year-old answer...

Answer (score 1):

If the Hostages where alive when you started the mission and you just skip past them and do the other objectives, they die because swat was unable to disarm the bomb. I did this once just to see what happened.